# Get the last inserted id as part of a multi-insert?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a tree of phones models and prices. At the moment I am looping over each model and inserting them into the database, getting the id, setting that as the `parent_id` of the prices and inserting the prices.

As the number of phone models and prices goes up this becomes a slower and slower experience.

Is there a way to do a bulk insert but in a way that allows me to get the last increment id within the current query?

e.g.

```
insert into my_table ('name', 'value', 'parent_id') values
('model', 'apple', 0),
@@parent_id = last_insert_id,
('iphone5s', '5.99', @@parent_id),
('iphoneX', '15.99', @@parent_id),
```

Comment: couldn't you use an automatic id, and a method from the language your using? (ex for php https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/sql/connect/php/pdo-lastinsertid?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: @pataluc why do that when the database can provide truly unique numbers ? Doing so in the client is a workaround and quite prone to problems

Comment: parent_id is an identity column, right?

Comment: You're asking two different questions. 1) how to get back a generated value - use the [OUTPUT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#examples) clause and `OUTPUT inserted.ID`. 2) How to store a tree in a single table, using a *bad* example - categories and products. The answer is A) Don't. Categories aren't products. Mixing them up violates basic design rules. Use different tables and B) If you want hierarchies, use `hierarchyid` or store a **single** XML or JSON value

Comment: As for why you *shouldn't* try to mix different types like you did, what does `value` represent? Is it a name? A number? Price? Where can I buy an iPhone X for $15.99 ?

Comment: `As the number of phone models and prices goes up this becomes a slower and slower experience.` yes, because the design is wrong and as a result, will always be slow.

Answer (score 0):

Use Scope_identity(),First Declare a variable and assign the last identity value in to variable.

```
DECLARE @i_LastIdentVal INT,
        @@parent_id INT

BEGIN TRY
    BEGIN TRANSACTION
INSERT INTO my_table (
            name, 
            value, 
            parent_id
            ) 
VALUES ('model', 'apple', 0),
       ('iphone5s', '5.99', @@parent_id),
       ('iphoneX', '15.99', @@parent_id)

SELECT @i_LastIdentVal = Scope_identity()

COMMIT TRANSACTION
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    DECLARE 
        @ErrorMessage NVARCHAR(4000),
        @ErrorSeverity INT,
        @ErrorState INT;
    SELECT 
        @ErrorMessage = ERROR_MESSAGE(),
        @ErrorSeverity = ERROR_SEVERITY(),
        @ErrorState = ERROR_STATE();
    RAISERROR (
        @ErrorMessage,
        @ErrorSeverity,
        @ErrorState    
        );
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
END CATCH
```

Note Make sure the inserting table should have created identity column earlier